# A function that selects the minimum value in a column is not the minimum and it's likely due to the column being a factor instead of numeric?

Tags: r

The dataset, system settings, function, description and result is as follows:

If one enters `AK` manually for `choice` and then check `stateOfChoice` and look under `30 day mortality by pneumonia`, one finds the numerical values of the hospitals, so the result should be `YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL` since it has the lowest value at ~9.5. However, I am getting `PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER`. All values for this particular state's 30 day mortality by pneumonia are filled in. Still, it's a class type factor. This wrong class type may very well be the problem as to why YUKON HOSPITAL is not coming up in the results. What can be done to fix the problem of having a different selection of hospital for 30 day mortality by pneumonia?

The system settings are `Windows 10` and `R 3.6.1`

[The original DATASET.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FTZJQLdw0PKw2bQ7XvxWnOITU7-yOCXC)

[DATASET with ALL values for 30 Day Mortality Rate Pneumonia filled in.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_sKokV1rcnAzjJsbRWqLTd2GL4GqAfHq)

The function call that is being used:

```
best("AK","pneumonia")
```

The function:

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
     #read file function

  #Reads the csv file
  dataTable  <- read.csv("outcome.csv", header = TRUE)

  #Passes the state argument to the choice variable
  choice <- state
  #selects all rows which match the state that was selected
  stateOfChoice <- dataTable[dataTable$State == choice,]
  stateOfChoice

  #Makes sure that only three of outcomes found in the csv file are selected
  if(outcome != "heart failure" && outcome != "heart attack" && outcome != "pneumonia"){
    print("wrong condition, try again")
    main()
  }

  #using the selected rows from above, return the minimum value of rate from heart attack and then use this selected row to find the hospital name
  else if (outcome == "heart attack"){


    heart_attack <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack),]
    heart_attack
    hospital <- heart_attack$Hospital.Name
    hospital
    return(hospital)
  }

  #Similar as above, but instead with heart failure
  else if (outcome == "heart failure"){
    heart_failure <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure),]
    hospital <- heart_failure$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

  #Similar as above, but instead with pneumonia
  else if (outcome == "pneumonia"){


    pneumonia <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia),]
    pneumonia
    hospital <- pneumonia$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

}
```

Comment: If you suspect its because its of `factor` class, you can always use `as.numeric(as.character(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what you've stated - your `Hospital.Name` column is a factor which means that the strings are encoded as numbers which throws off your `which.min` function.
You just need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `read.csv` function to fix this.

```
dataTable  <- read.csv("outcome.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your numeric columns in the data file have the words 'Not Available' in some cells, so are being read in as character or factor.  The `which.min` is therefore returning the first value alphabetically rather than numerically.

To solve this, for each of your columns `X` on which you want to use numerical functions, do this first...

```
stateOfChoice$X <- as.numeric(as.character(stateOfChoice$X))
```

You can only convert from factor to numeric by going via character as an intermediate step.